# Parsing error in DATEDIFF php

Tags: php, sql, date

Below is my sql query in php.

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl_Players I WHERE DATEDIFF( DAY , NOW( ) , I.FirstLoginTime ) <1 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

FirstLoginTime is field in sql table which has value of DateTime.

I want all the data inserted before one day.

It gives me error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' I.FirstLoginTime) &lt; 1
LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3
```

Thanks For Help.

Comment: DATEDIFF takes 2 arguments, you are passing it 3

Comment: How could i get to know if difference is in day or hour something else.

Comment: what's wrong with the result when you remove *DAY ,* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my knowledge, the DATEDIFF function in mysql takes two arguments, 
you can check it on this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

And you are referring to Sql-Server right now which takes three arguments but in mysql it does not.

So if you will write as follow, it won't give error

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl_Players I WHERE DATEDIFF(  NOW( ) , I.FirstLoginTime ) <1 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: wouldn't a mysql function be in the mysql manual not the php manual? Also w3schools is full fo dangerous *crap* don't reference it here

Comment: better to link to the actual manual/docs -  [`DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff